# Ill posedness of a PDE - equation on the equivalence class

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Let $X\subset \mathbb{R}^n$, $Y\subset \mathbb{R}^m$ $f: \mathbb{R}^n\times \mathbb{R}^m$ smooth.

I am interested in the couples $(\phi,h)$ ($\phi:X\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ continuously differentiable and $h:X\times Y\rightarrow \mathbb{R}) $ smooth) solutions of the  PDE 
$$
 \nabla_x \phi(x) \cdot f(x,y) + h(x,y)=0
$$

Let $g:X\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be continously differentiable.
Clearly, if $(\phi,h)$ is solution then $(\phi+g,h-\nabla_x g(x) \cdot f(x,u))$ is also solution...
So the issue is that this problem is not well posed.

I am trying to find a constraint on the set of solutions $\{(\phi,h)\}$ so that it would avoid this class of solutions. In short, a constraint on $\phi$, $h$ or both so that the EDP is well posed concerning, at least, this pitfall non uniqueness.
Quotient equation so that we manipulate only class ? how is it pertinent ?

We can first look the 1-dimensionnal case:
$$
\phi'(x) f(x,y) + h(x,y)=0
$$
...